# multithreading issues with FMDB

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, fmdb

I am new to FMDB, I am using FMDBQueue to avoid any threading issues, but for some reason when it try to get the data from and operation queue, it is going to semaphore wait. I have attached a thread stack, can someone please check it and help me with understanding the issue?. How can we make sure that we run FMDB calls on a single thread?.

[image: Thread stack]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FMDatabaseQueue isn't reentrant.  Thread 23 is trying to do that.  (You can't call inDatabase: from within inDatabase:)

Comment: I have 3 threads doing inDatabase. Can you please help in understanding the issue clearly. I am confused. @ccgus